# transform text to list

Tags: php, html, regex, list

I'm having some trouble with Converting Text to a list. The situation is that I get text like the following from the database:

```
"Hello, my name is michael, my hobbys are:
- computers
- guitar
and some more blabla "
```

No I want to transform the listed points(computers&guitar in this case) into an unordered html list, so the resulst should look like this:

```
"Hello, my name is michael, my hobbys are:
<ul>
<li>computers<li>
<li>guitar</li>
</ul>
and some more blabla ".
```

I think that the best solution would be doing this by regex, but my knowledge there isnt good enough to realise this. I tried it by replacing all `/\n- /` width a `<li>` tag, which worked. But how do I get the closing `</li>`, and even more confusing for me, how do I get the both `<ul>` tags?

Thank you in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax looks almost identical to [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown), a simple markup language. The only difference is a little bit of whitespace:

```
Hello, my name is Michael, my hobbies are:

 - Computers
 - Guitar

and some more blabla
```

It's converted to this:

```
<p>Hello, my name is Michael, my hobbies are:</p>

<ul>
    <li>Computers</li>
    <li>Guitar</li>
</ul>

<p>and some more blabla</p>
```

There are a few [PHP Markdown](http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/) projects that I think you'll find useful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the way Ynhockey posted seems to be faster for me. If I find the time, I'll take a look at markdown, it looks quite interesting.

Comment: @MichaelKunst: Micro optimization isn't going to do you much good. Generate the HTML once and cache it for later. There's really no use in reinventing the wheel here.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of ways to do this, including regex, but in your specific case the explode() function should suffice. You can do:

```
$array = explode("\n", $string);
```

Now your $array will have "Hello, my name is michael, my hobbys are:" in the first slot, "- computers" in the second, etc.

Then go over the array, and for each element that begins with "-", turn it into <li>element</li>

This is a very vanilla way of doing it, but it should be efficient and doesn't require the use of regular expressions.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, it would be best to do regular expressions

Comment: no, definitly not, in this case, simple line-by-line parsing as mentionned in @Ynhockey's answer is better adapted